# Post Processing of Resized Image In clustered environment

Tags: amazon-s3, imageresizer

Been playing with ImageResizer for a bit now, and trying to do something, I am having trouble understanding the way to go about it.

Mainly I would like to stick to the idea of using the pipeline, and not trying to cheat it.

So.... Let's say, I pretty standard use ImageResizer For something like:
    giants_logo.jpg?w=280&h=100
The File giants_logo.jpg
Processing Request is for a resized version of 'w=280&h=100'

In a clustered environment, what will happen is if this same request is served by 3 machines.
All 3 would end up doing the resize, and then storing their cached version in a local folder on disc. I could leverage a shared drive or something, but that has it's own limitations.

What I am looking to do, is get the processed file, and then copy it back up to the DB or S3 where the main images are served from.

My thought is.... I might have to write somehting like DiscCache, but with a complelty different guts, using the DB or S3 as the back end instead of the file system.

I realize the point of caching is speed, and what I am suggesting is negating that aspect..... but that's not the case if we layer the things maybe.

Anyway, What I am focused on is trying to keep track of the files generated, as well as avoid processing on multiple servers.

Any thoughts on the route I should look at to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR;** When DiskCache **actually** stops working well (usually between 1 and 20 million unique images), then switch to a CDN (unless it's too expensive), or a reverse proxy (unless your data set is *really* too huge to be bound by mortal infrastructure).

For petabyte data sets on the cheap when performance isn't king, it's a good plan. But for most people, it's premature. Even users with upwards of 20TB (source images) still use DiskCache. Really. Terabyte drives are cheap.

---

#### Latency is the killer.

To make this work you would need a central Redis server. MSSQL won't cut it (at least not on a VM or commodity hardware, we've tried). Given a Redis server, you can track what is done and stored (and perhaps even what is in progress, to de-duplicate effort in real time, as DiskCache does).

If you can track it, you can reuse it, and you can delete it. Reuse *will* be slower, since you're doubling the network traffic, moving the result twice. (But also decreasing it linearly  with the number of servers in the cluster for source image fetches).

If bandwidth saturation is your bottleneck (very common), this could make performance **worse**. In fact, unless your read/write ratio is write and CPU heavy, you'll likely see worse performance than duplicated CPU effort under individual disk caches.

If you have the infrastructure to test it, put DiskCache on a SAN or shared drive; this will give you a solid estimate of the performance you can expect (assuming said drive and your blob storage system have comparable IO perf).

However, it's a fair amount of work, and you're essentially duplicating a subset of the functionality of reverse proxy (but with worse performance, since every response has to be proxied through the unlucky cluster server, instead of being spooled directly from disk).

#### CDNs and Reverse proxies to the rescue

Amazon CloudFront or Varnish can serve quite well as reverse proxies/caches for a web farm or cluster. Now, you'll have a bit less control over the 'garbage collection' process, but... also less code to maintain.

There's also [ARR](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing), but I've heard neither success nor failure stories about it.

#### But it sounds fun!

Send me a Github link and I'll help out.

I'd love to get a Redis-coordinated, cloud-agnostic poor-man's blob cache system out there. You bring the petabytes and infrastructure, I'll help you with the integration and troublesome bits. Efficient HTTP proxying is probably the hardest part; the rest is state management and basic threading.

Comment: Great answer. I see your points, and you mentioned some of my concerns from the get go with the thought process. 
I think I will start with a look at how/if I can leverage cloudfront for my need, and if not, then we can discuss the bigger project..... might happen :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at a modified AzureReader2 plugin at https://github.com/orbyone/Sensible.ImageResizer.Plugins.AzureReader2

This implementation stores the transformed image back to the Azure blob container on the initial requests, so subsequent requests are redirected to that copy.